# How do I make the aspect effective in different situations?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How do I make the aspect effective in different situations?

I have a simple service.

```
/**
 * Target Service.
 */
@Service
public class TargetService {

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

An Aspect.

```
/**
 * Aspect.
 */
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.TargetService.*(..))")
    public void targetMethod() {

    }

    @Around("targetMethod()")
    public Object proceedGetByCondition(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Proxy ...");
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }

}
```

Then i have a service named `TestService`.

```
/**
 * Test service.
 */
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TargetService targetService;

    public void test() {
        targetService.sayHello();
    }

}
```

Another test service.

```
/**
 * Another test service.
 */
@Service
public class AnotherTestService {

    @Autowired
    private TargetService targetService;

    public void test() {
        targetService.sayHello();
    }

}
```

Finally, this is my main class.

```
/**
 * Main app
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplication(MainApp.class).run(args);
        TestService testService = context.getBean(TestService.class);
        testService.test();

        AnotherTestService anotherTestService = context.getBean(AnotherTestService.class);
        anotherTestService.test();

    }

}
```

What i want is this:

If i call `TestService#test()` , `Aspect` will work. So it will print

```
Proxy ...
Hello
```

If i call `AnotherTestService#test()`, `Aspect` will not work. So it will only print Hello.

```
Hello
```

How can i do this?

I tried `within` , but it doesn't work.

Please give me some idea. Thank you!

Comment: Is this possiable?

Comment: This should work. Could you please share the complete code as a github project or so? By any chance there is a duplicate `TargetService` bean in the project ?

Comment: Github is `git@github.com:fengkai/aop-test.git` . Please check it, thank you.

Comment: unable to find the repo . could you please confirm the URL ?

Comment: Sorry, can you try open this `https://github.com/fengkai/aop-test` in browser?

Comment: code works as expected. it prints the advice code before "Hello" for both cases

Comment: I want `TestService#test()` print "Proxy ...",  `AnotherTestService#test()` not print "Proxy ..".

Comment: How can i do it ?

Comment: Sorry . I misunderstood your question. That is not possible with the current pointcut expression with SpringAOP. It is targeting `TargetService.sayHello()` and would advice every execution of the method. Alternatively advice can target `TestService.test()`